# Make POST request for WMS in Leaflet for big values of cql_filter

Tags: leaflet, wms, cql-filter, http-post

I am passing a spatial query such as `CONTAINS(geom, POLYGON((// geometry)))` in the `cql_filter`, but for big polygons `GET` request the allowed URI length is violated and hence my requests is getting HTTP 414 status code 'URI too long'.

I looked for the solution so someone suggested me to use POST request and it worked, but I don't know how to modify the WMS GET request in Leaflet to POST?

Comment: Converting a GET to a POST is a plain- vanilla IT task, probably better suited to searching on [so] proper.

Comment: Is it your WMS? if so you can configure the allowed limit ~ http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#limitrequestline

Comment: see also https://anitagraser.com/2010/06/09/getmap-from-geoserver-using-http-post/

Comment: SO may be a slow way to go.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54397933/using-leaflet-with-http-post-to-send-big-wkt-text-to-geoserver

Comment: The problem is that leaflet append the image in the div element of the map container and specify the image source in the src tag which by default supports get method, how can i make it work for post request?

Comment: Did you solve your problem

Answer (score 2):

You have to implement your own **TileLayer.WMS** layer and override **createTile** method

```
export class CustomWMSLayer extends TileLayer.WMS {

  loadTile = async (
    coords: Coords,
    done: DoneCallback,
    img: HTMLImageElement
  ) => {
    const fullUrl = this.getTileUrl(coords);
    const [url, urlparams] = fullUrl.split("?");

    const response = await fetch(url, {
      method: "POST",
      body: urlparams,
      headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      },
    });
    const blobData = await response.blob();
    const fileReader = new FileReader();

    fileReader.onload = () => {
      img.src = fileReader.result as string;
      done(undefined, img);
    };
    fileReader.readAsDataURL(blobData);
  };

  createTile = (coords: Coords, done: DoneCallback): HTMLElement => {
    const img = document.createElement("img");
    this.loadTile(coords, done, img);

    return img;
  };
}
```