# MapServer POST request from GET string

Tags: mapserver, xml, mapfile

I have a very long GET request to the MapServer due to a large number of objects in a dynamic variable "object_id". (object_id=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,.........)

My query string is: *"https://wms-server.local/wms?map.layer[polygon].class[0].style[0]=OUTLINECOLOR+200+64+150+WIDTH+4&object_id=9&service=WMS&request=GetMap&layers=polygon&styles=&format=image%2Fpng&transparent=true&version=1.1.1&width=256&height=256&srs=EPSG%3A3857&bbox=-20037508.342789244,0,-10018754.171394622,10018754.171394628"*

MapServer returns an error 414 (GET request limit)

How do correctly XML file from my GET request to get tiles (DRAWING)

P.S. Maybe there is a more correct solution for an unknown number of objects? (I need get tiles to Leaflet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn this into a POST request and pass in your parameters as key=value pairs.

Create a string `SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=` and then make a POST request.
You'll also need to set the `Content-type` header in the request to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

JavaScript example:

```js
const url = "https://wms-server.local/wms";
const postData = "SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&LAYERS=your_layers&WIDTH=800&HEIGHT=600&FORMAT=image/png&CRS=EPSG:4326&BBOX=0,0,10,10";

fetch(url, {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  },
  body: postData
});
```

There is a Leaflet example at the end of https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/5549

See also [Make POST request for WMS in Leaflet for big values of cql_filter](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/324136/make-post-request-for-wms-in-leaflet-for-big-values-of-cql-filter) and